# Using code from standard library to stop output from exiting in Turbo C++

Tags: c++, c, standard-library, turbo-c++

Many of folks here are telling me to stop using `clrscr()`, `getch()` etc. and I have started learning C++ with the standard library and now that I want to follow the standard library how would I stop the output from immediate exit after run?

```
include <iostream.h>
include <conio.h> // Instead of using this

    void main(){
        cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
        getch(); // Instead of using this
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `getch()` with `cin.get()` like this:

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

For more details see [get() function documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/). Just for reference you may do this, for example, to wait until user pressed a specific character:

```
void main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    cout << "Press Q to quit." << endl;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), 'Q');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly run the binary from command line. In that case after the program is finished executing the output will still be in the terminal and you can see it.

Else if you are using an IDE which closes the terminal as soon as the execution is complete, you can use any blocking operation. The simplest is `scanf (" %c", &dummy);` or `cin >> dummy;` or even `getchar ();` and what Adriano has suggested. Although you need to press Enter key, as these are buffered input operations.